# Text disappear on click, but new text entered disappears to

Tags: javascript, html, hover

Well I am making my first landing page, something not overly professional, I want to get in the hang of being able to make simple web pages myself.

So my issue is that whenever you click on the textbox, the text disappears. Which it should. But when the user enters text, clicks off the text box and clicks back on it, that text disappears.

How can I make it so that the newly entered text does not disappear?

My current code for the text fields:

http://pastie.org/8366114

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" id="form" 
  onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your First Name';" 
  onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Enter Your First Name')this.value='';" 
  onFocus="this.value=''">
</input></br>
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Email" id="form" 
  onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your Email';" 
  onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Enter Your Email')this.value='';" 
  onFocus="this.value=''">
</input></br>
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Phone Number" id="form" 
  onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your Phone Number';" 
  onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Enter Your Phone Number')this.value='';" 
  onFocus="this.value=''">
</input></br>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value=""></input>
```

I apologize for not posting it on here, but I don't know how to do the code block thing..

Comment: copy ad paste code, then highlight and press "ctrl + k"

Comment: if there is a answer that satisfies you, you can accept it by clicking on the check next to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to do this with javascript all you need is

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your First Name';" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Your First Name')this.value='';" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/R7fBr/4/)

however you can just simply use the html5 `placeholder` [reference](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)

also

1. dont use the same `id` more then once, instead use `class`.
2. input is self-closing (like `<br>`)
3. `</br>` is wrong use `<br>` or `<br />`

here is a working version of your code, i also added `submit` as the `value` for your `button`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" class="form"><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="form"><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" class="form"><br/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/R7fBr/3/)

Comment: I did not leave a value for the Submit button because it will actually place the text "submit" on the image button. My button is an image type of button. Can't believe I was doing all this javascript and trying to work around IE all this time when there is this simple solution.. Ty :)

Comment: @Travis btw, even in javascript you could write a function to reduce the code very considerably.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" id="form" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your First Name';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Your First Name')this.value='';" />
```

or if you are using HTML5, you can use placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" id="form"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the onfocus event the same as the onclick event, e.g:

```
onfocus="javascript: if (this.value == 'Enter Your First Name') this.value = '';"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onFocus="this.value=''"
```

This is causing your text fields to be reset to blank unconditionally.

You probably only need onclick or onfocus here, and since onfocus will take into account tabbing into the field as well as clicking it with the mouse, I would recommend moving the code from onclick to onfocus and deleting onclick altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Remove content from form onclick:

in haml:

```
= f.text_field :title, :value => 'Name', :onfocus => "if (this.value=='Name') this.value='';"
```

in html:

```
<input id="project_title" name="project[title]" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value='';" type="text" value="Name">
```

Comment: oops %) foget html5 attributes placeholder="Your Data"